# simulate the displace modifier on a curve using Geometry Nodes

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

There is no *displace* modifier for curves in Blender.

Would it be possible to simulate it using **Geometry Nodes** ?

My goal is to be able to softly randomize the position of the vertexes of my curves.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible by using a texture node and moving the points with `Set Position`.

[image]

The only problem is
 At the output of the *Geometry Nodes* modifier you can also output the curve, but this curve is only available as long as you do not try to make it available as a editable curve by applying the modifier.

See [Can I create Bezier curves with Geometry Nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/265910/145249).