# Curve Modifier not working with a Geometry-Nodes curve as the "Curve Object"?

Tags: geometry-nodes, curve-modifier

I have an object I want to deform along a curve. For that, I'm using a Curve Modifier and the curve is procedurally made with geometry-nodes, but when I select it as the "Curve Object" it doesn't work (the object stays unaffected).

It works perfectly with normal curves, just not with the geo-nodes one.

---

This is the Curve Modifier:

[image: Curve Modifier with the geo-nodes curve selected]

---

This is the procedural curve (it has the Mesh to Curve node):

[image: Curve and Geo-Nodes]

---

Is there something I need to do to use a geo-nodes curve on a Curve Modifier, or is it impossible and the only way is to make a procedural "Curve Modifier" with geo-nodes inside the object?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is indeed "impossible". Geometry Nodes only output a mesh and no curves. However, as long as your curve is not changed in time and can be used as a single object, you can solve this with the following answer: [Can I create real/editable curves with Geometry Nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/299847/145249)

Comment: @quellenform The curve doesn't "change in time" as in keyframe animations but can be procedurally changed with a slider in viewport. Does that count? (I started trying to do the "geo-nodes curve modifier" meanwhile.) Thanks!